# How to send Array with the formdata in ajax request to mvc action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, form-data

I was trying to send array with the form data to an action with Ajax request but whenever I do I receive both the form data and the array empty

```
$scope.SubmitForm = function () {
        var sLangs = $("#supportedLanguages").data("kendoMultiSelect").value();    

        var formdata = new FormData($('#frmAppSettings').get(0));

        alert(formdata.SelectedLanguages);

        var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("frmAppSettings"));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/AppMenuMaker/AppSettings",
            data: JSON.stringify({ AppSettingsView: formdata, SelectedLangs: sLangs }),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function () {

            }
        });
    }`
```

I have my action as following

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult AppSettings( ApplicationSettingsViewModel AppSettingsView, int[] SelectedLangs)
    {

    }
```

Any help ?

Comment: Try contentType : 'application/json'

Comment: Did you try something like this before ?

Comment: I have had similar situations where putting proper content type worked for me

Comment: I doubt I can receive multiple objects , I think Json.Stringfy puts them in one object..

Comment: I tried to change the content type now I am receiving the second object only :)

Comment: Can you confirm AppSettingsView is not null in client side? Try debugging in browser. If sent, it should bind to the model.

Comment: You need to add the other values to the `FormData` object using `.append()` and the ajax option must be `data: formdata,` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)) although of your element with `id="supportedLanguages"` is inside the form, then its already been added to the `FormData` object anyway.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I used the append function now I can see that the data sent contains 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SelectedLanguages"

1,2
' but when I receive it on the server it becomes empty array

Comment: You need to do its as `formdata.append('SelectedLanguages', 1);` `formdata.append('SelectedLanguages', 2);`

Comment: It worked !! Thank you so much @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FormData` is a set of name/value pairs representing form controls and their values, and is sent as `multipart/form-data`, You cannot `stringify()` it and/or send it with separate objects. You need to append name/value pairs to it.

If the element with `id="supportedLanguages"` is inside the form with `id="frmAppSettings"`, then your code

```
var formdata = new FormData($('#frmAppSettings').get(0));
```

will correctly add the values of the `<select>` to the `FormData` object. If not, then you need to append each value in the array, for example

```
var formdata = new FormData($('#frmAppSettings').get(0));
$.each($("#supportedLanguages").val(), function(index, item) {
    formdata .append('SelectedLangs', item);
});
```

and then the ajax options need to be

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("AppSettings", "AppMenuMaker")', // use @Url.Action() to generate your url's
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function () {
    }
});
```